# Why might a nodeJS API work locally but fail in production?

Tags: node.js, curl, mean-stack

An API method I've been using without problems on localhost:3000/userinfo suddenly gives an "Empty Reply From Server" when I upload that same code to my web server and send a POST request to myserver.com:3000/userinfo.

Even more strange is that if the JSON returned by user info does not contain an array of objects, there is no error locally or remotely.

I don't know how much detail will be useful, and how much will just clutter this question. This one is especially strange so I'd like to approach it very generally. In other words, I don't think I'm missing a semi colon this time because the API function works perfectly when run on a local server.

Comment: Did the port `3000` opened on server ?

Comment: Can you check the logs or something to confirm that your app is actually getting the request when you try to open 'myserver.com:3000/userinfo'?

Answer (score 0):

So without a whole lot of detail, the only thing I can suggest here is make sure your ports are correct. You said 4200 locally but its 3000 on your server? The error you're getting also suggests ( I'm assuming cURL? ) that it couldn't connect at all to your server, which furthers my hypothesis.

Alternatively, there could be an error in your API and its "crashing" without logging anything, which would also cause an empty reply error.
Be sure to capture unhandled exceptions using process events to log out errors!

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_events

```js
process.on('uncaughtException', function (error) {
 console.error("GOT UNCAUGHT EXECPTION!", error)
 process.exit(1);
})
```

Comment: The port 4200 was a typo. I was trying to say that I'm using a browser on my local machine to make API calls to a node server on my local machine, without problems. When I use a browser on my local machine to make API calls (same code, git controlled) to the server, I get the empty responses.